# Check if an environment is empty

Tags: environments

I have got a custom environment which (sometimes) may not have anything inside it. Under those circumstances I need to take some special actions. Is there a way to check whether my environment is empty?

Here is the first idea, though not very useful I am afraid.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{abletocheckempty}
{
  % Do this if the environment is not empty
  Not empty

  % And do this if the environment is empty
  Empty
}
{
  % No change in closing behavior 
}                              

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
  There is some text or even command here.
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abletocheckempty}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
\end{abletocheckempty}

\end{document}
```

If we take it a step further, and use the [`environ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ?lang=en) package, we can formulate a code like this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{abletocheckempty}
{\notblank{\BODY}{Not empty}{Empty}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
  There is some texts or even commands here.
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abletocheckempty}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
\end{abletocheckempty}

\end{document}
```

The above code compiles fine but I get,

> ```
> Not empty
> Not empty
> ```

as output.

What is it I could be missing here?

I understand that as stated in the manual for [`etoolbox`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/environ/environ.pdf),

> `\ifblank{<string>}{<true>}{<false>}`
>
> Expands to `<true>` if the `<string>` is blank (empty or spaces), and
>   to `<false>` otherwise. The `<string>` is not expanded in the test.

So, I tried using an `\expandafter` before  `\notblank`, without any avail.

Comment: You want `\ifdefempty\BODY{<true code>}{<false code>}`.  When you do `\ifblank{\BODY}` it counts the tokens in the curly braces which is obviously not empty because there is `\BODY` even though the replacement text of `\BODY` would be empty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use other etoolbox features as noted in comments, or just test `\BODY` directly, this makes not empty, empty, empty

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{abletocheckempty}
{\ifx\BODY\@empty
 Empty%
\else
 Not empty%
\fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
  There is some texts or even commands here.
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abletocheckempty}

\begin{abletocheckempty}
\end{abletocheckempty}

\begin{abletocheckempty}\end{abletocheckempty}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The lipsum text doesn't show up for me, only the empty/not empty.

Comment: It was a silly mishap. It turns out I needed to replace `Not Empty` with `\BODY`. I've edited the answer to express this.

Comment: Separately, I wonder if you have a suggestion of how to handle cases where the `\BODY` reduces to whitespace, putting a blank line between the section opening and closing breaks your solution.

Comment: the site really doesn't support asking new questions as comments on old questions, would be better to ask a new question, but you could add a test for `\ifx\BODY\zzpar` where zzpar is defined by `\def\zzpar{\par}`

Comment: sorry my initial reply to your lipsum comment was misleading, the enviornment body is not typeset here, as requested in the question it just outputs debug output of empty or not empty (I rolled back the edit)